# Filling gaps between start end timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mariadb

I'm trying to find a query to fill gaps between a start and end timestamp. The gaps/intervals should be minute wise. My goal is to get a time-series to create a diagram based on the results to visualize a time period for each record.

**Sample date**

```
    create table tbl(
      id int, value int, dateStart timestamp, dateEnd timestamp
    );

    insert into tbl values
    (1, 4, '2020-01-04 16:29:00', '2020-01-04 16:33:00'),
    (2, 3, '2020-01-04 18:29:00', '2020-01-04 18:33:00'),
    (3, 3, '2020-07-16 09:10:00', '2020-07-16 09:12:00');


| id  | value    | dateStart           | dateEnd             |
| --- | -------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 4        | 2020-01-04 16:29:00 | 2020-01-04 16:33:00 |
| 2   | 3        | 2020-01-04 18:29:00 | 2020-01-04 18:30:00 |
| 3   | 3        | 2020-07-16 09:10:00 | 2020-07-16 09:12:00 |
| .   | .        | .                   | .                   |
| .   | .        | .                   | .                   |
| .   | .        | .                   | .                   |
```

**Expected Output**

```
| id  | value    | date                |
| --- | -------- | ------------------- | 
| 1   | 4        | 2020-01-04 16:29:00 |
| 2   | 4        | 2020-01-04 16:30:00 |
| 3   | 4        | 2020-01-04 16:31:00 |
| 4   | 4        | 2020-01-04 16:32:00 |
| 5   | 4        | 2020-01-04 16:33:00 |
| 6   | 3        | 2020-01-04 18:29:00 |
| 7   | 3        | 2020-01-04 18:30:00 |
| 8   | 3        | 2020-07-16 09:10:00 |
| 9   | 3        | 2020-07-16 09:11:00 |
| 10  | 3        | 2020-07-16 09:12:00 |
```

I'm not very familiar with CTE and cursors, yet. 
Any suggestion/help how to solve it best?

Comment: Which version of MySQL or MariaDB are you running?

Comment: MariaDB 10.4.11, but no problem to use mysql or any other mariaDB/mysql version.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Data display is handled by a third party solution, the current data needs to be transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one (rather inefficient) way to do it is to use a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, value, dateStart, dateEnd from tbl
    union all
    select id, value, dateStart + interval 1 minute, dateEnd 
    from cte
    where dateStart < dateEnd
)
select row_number() over(order by id) id, value, dateStart date 
from cte
order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2af6655a63e8e3ad7e53e7fdc84b5f7b)**:

```
id | value | date               
-: | ----: | :------------------
 1 |     4 | 2020-01-04 16:29:00
 2 |     4 | 2020-01-04 16:30:00
 3 |     4 | 2020-01-04 16:31:00
 4 |     4 | 2020-01-04 16:32:00
 5 |     4 | 2020-01-04 16:33:00
 6 |     3 | 2020-01-04 18:29:00
 7 |     3 | 2020-01-04 18:30:00
 8 |     3 | 2020-07-16 09:10:00
 9 |     3 | 2020-07-16 09:11:00
10 |     3 | 2020-07-16 09:12:00
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! What would be a more efficient way, stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Much more efficient is to use MariaDB's "seq" pseudo tables:

```
( SELECT '2000-01-01' + INTERVAL seq DAY AS dy FROM seq_0_to_36524 )
```

will generate a century's worth dates in 3 ms.  Yes, milliseconds.

```
SELECT s.dy
    FROM ( SELECT '2020-01-04 18:29:00' + INTERVAL seq MINUTE AS dy
                                      FROM seq_0_to_1440 ) AS s
    WHERE s.dy <= '2020-01-04 18:33:00';

+---------------------+
| dy                  |
+---------------------+
| 2020-01-04 18:29:00 |
| 2020-01-04 18:30:00 |
| 2020-01-04 18:31:00 |
| 2020-01-04 18:32:00 |
| 2020-01-04 18:33:00 |
+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That generates a day's worth of dates (in 1ms), then limits to the desired range.  In your case, you would `LEFT JOIN` to the your sparse table.